# How to get elastic cache node ip address with cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloud-formation to create an elasitc cache cluster with redis engine.

I would like to create a route53 DNS for that node.

Following [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html) They use AWS CLI to get that nodes IP, but this doesn't work when trying to get it in the JSON script itself.

Consider the following:

> ```
> "DNS": {
>   "Type": "AWS::Route53::HostedZone",
>   "DependsOn": [
>     "VPC"
>   ],
>   "Properties": {
>     "HostedZoneConfig": {
>       "Comment": "Private hosted zone for company.com"
>     },
>     "Name": "internal.company.com.",
>     "VPCs": [
>       {
>         "VPCId": {
>           "Ref": "VPC"
>         },
>         "VPCRegion": {
>           "Ref": "AWS::Region"
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> },
> "DNSRedis" : {
>         "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
>         "DependsOn": [
>     "DNS",
>     "RedisElasticacheCluster"
>   ],
>         "Properties" : {
>             "HostedZoneName" : "internal.company.com.",
>             "Comment" : "Redis record",
>             "Name" : "redis.internal.conpany.com.",
>             "Type" : "A",
>             "TTL" : "900",
>             "ResourceRecords" : [
>                 "$cluster_config['RedisElasticacheCluster'][0]['CacheNodes'][0]['Endpoint']['Address']"
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> ```

produces the following error:

```
Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address encountered at $cluster_config['RedisElasticacheCluster'][0]['CacheNodes'][0]['Endpoint']['Address']
```

I Get an error when using Memcached as well:

> ```
> "DNSMemcached" : {
>         "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
>         "DependsOn": [
>     "DNS",
>     "MemcachedElasticacheCluster"
>   ],
>         "Properties" : {
>             "HostedZoneName" : "internal.company.com.",
>             "Comment" : "Redis record",
>             "Name" : "memcached.internal.company.com.",
>             "Type" : "A",
>             "TTL" : "900",
>             "ResourceRecords" : [
>                 {
>                   "Fn::GetAtt": [
>                     "MemcachedElasticacheCluster",
>                     "ConfigurationEndpoint.Address"
>                   ]
>       }
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> ```

produces the following error:

```
Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: ARRDATAIllegalIPv4Address encountered at tes-me-1wqeucxfrxr7x.euoka1.cfg.use1.cache.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: The solution to the problem was the type of record for memcached. "A". When i changed to "CNAME" it worked, for redis i haven't found the solution